# Jquery Menu Request

Tags: jquery

I want a jquery menu like this link

the menu in link is in Flash format

[Flash Menu](http://www.atid1.com/default/)

when i hover on parent menu with mouse all sub menus will open

---

I think now this is the correct answer

```
<div class="hoverMenuItem" id="item1">
    Menu Item</div>
<div class="hoverMenuItem" id="item2">
    Menu Item</div>
<div class="hoverMenu" style="display: none; position: absolute;">
    <!--menu laid out-->
</div>
<div class="hoverMenu" style="display: none; position: absolute;">
    <!--menu laid out-->
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.hoverMenuItem').mouseover(function () {
            //var id = $(this).attr("id");
            //var itemNum = id.substring(4);
            //$('#menu' + itemNum).slideDown(250);
            $('.hoverMenu').slideDown(250);
        });
        $('.hoverMenuItem').mouseout(function () {
            //var id = $(this).attr("id");
            //var itemNum = id.substring(4);
            //$('#menu' + itemNum).slideUp(250);
            $('.hoverMenu').slideUp(250);
        });
    });
</script>
```

but there is a problem

in this way how can we Determine childs for each parent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here's a final answer (Sorry it took so long).

http://jsfiddle.net/htBPp/6/

I redesigned my approach, and used the .hover function on the wrapper div (menuSection).  This worked perfectly.  So, there you are.

/* Old stuff, preserved  for posterity

EDIT- This is the new approach.

This is where I'm at so far- it's pretty close.  If you go back up to the menu items, it'll hide and then show the menu... you'll have to get clever to solve that.

http://jsfiddle.net/htBPp/4/

EDIT- This is my first shot at the answer.

```
<div class="hoverMenuItem" id="item1">Menu Item</div>
<div class="hoverMenu" id="menu1" style="display:none; position:absolute;"><!--menu laid out--></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.hoverMenuItem').mouseover(function(){
         var id=$(this).attr("id");
         var itemNum=id.substring(3);
         $('#menu'+itemNum).slideDown(250);
    });
    $('.hoverMenuItem').mouseout(function(){
         var id=$(this).attr("id");
         var itemNum=id.substring(3);
         $('#menu'+itemNum).slideUp(250);
    });
</script>
```

Something very similar to this will pretty much do it.  You will have to figure out how to avoid triggering the mouseout event when you go onto the menu, though (probably add the menu as a child element of the menu item).

EDIT:
So, starting from there, this is a quick and dirty fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/htBPp/

Inside the menu, you can setup the layout however you want and line it up with the items above.

*/

Comment: Thanks , but i think that id.substring(4); is correct , and another thing is that , in that link there is one parent object for all sub menus i think , but in your sample for each menu theme is one submenu that havent relation with the others

Comment: Ah, you're right on both counts.  I suppose you can just change it to one parent div that surrounds all the menu items, and then put the mouseover on that, with the menu inside of that div (still hidden).

Comment: Thanks dear Chaosphere

now i think for each menu parent we may have an Div as child of the parent submenu

and when we mouseover on the each parent menu Item , for example bg of it's child will change

am i right ?

Comment: We can do that, yes.  All that it requires is another line or two in the mouseover function for the menu/menuitem functions- substring the ids, then add a "selected" css class to that div.